# Is it right or wrong to give answer to "Azaan" while in washroom?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, adhan

Today this happened to me that i was in washroom and there is a call from prayer and i don't have any knowledge about what to do now..
Is it right if i give answer to Azaan in washroom?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by washroom? There's a clear cut between a toilet and a place you can wash your hands or bath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't give answer to "Azzan" because in washroom you even can't talk.In washroom it is prohibited to speak because when you speak your Angel's come inside and they can't see you in that position in which you are.Also the place where you are is not able to give the answer to "Azzan".

Comment: This answer would profit from evidences supporting your claims.

Answer (score 1):

As if you are in washroom and this situation occurred like in your religion its good to answer Azan but if you are doing ablution then you can answer but in case if you are using toilet or taking 'Gusal' then its not better to answer in that case. And in these situation that will be not considered as a sin.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is right to give answer of azan if you are out such place like toilet.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for that? (See [answer]).